# PHP Loop through multi-dimensional array into new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this...

```
[level1] => Array
(
    [random475item] => Array
        (
            [attr1] => tester1
            [attr2] => tester2
            [attr3] => tester3
        )
    [random455item] => Array
        (
            [attr1] => tester1
            [attr2] => tester2
            [attr3] => tester3
        )
)
```

I am trying to get the values of the `attr2` fields in a new array. I can specify a specific like this...

```
$newarray = array();
newarray [] = $array['level1']['random475item']['attr2'];
newarray [] = $array['level1']['random455item']['attr2'];
```

But is there a way to automate this as it could be 50 random items coming up and I don't want to have to keep adding them manually.

Comment: how many levels do you have? is the depth fixed?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php and the code below at
https://3v4l.org/8j3ae

```
<?php 
$array = ['level1' => [
    'item1' => [
        'attr1' => 'test1',
        'attr2' => 'test2',
        'attr3' => 'test3'
    ],
    'item2' => [
        'attr1' => 'test4',
        'attr2' => 'test5',
        'attr3' => 'test6'
    ],
]];

$values = array_column($array['level1'], 'attr2');

var_dump($values);
```

creates

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` for that :

```
$array = ['level1' => [
    'item1' => [
        'attr1' => 'test1',
        'attr2' => 'test2',
        'attr3' => 'test3'
    ],
    'item2' => [
        'attr1' => 'test4',
        'attr2' => 'test5',
        'attr3' => 'test6'
    ],
]];

// parse every item
$values = array_map(function($item) {
    // for each item, return the value 'attr2'
    return $item['attr2'];
}, $array['level1']);
```

I have created a [sandbox for you to try](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bx74);

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` statement will be solved your case

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($array['level1'] as $randomItemKey => $randomItemValue){
   $newarray[] = $randomItemValue['attr2'];
}
```

Comment: You can drop the key if not needed: `foreach($array['level1'] as $value)`

Answer (score 1):

If the values can occur at any point in the array, you can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) which will loop through all of the values (only leaf nodes) and you can check if it is an `attr2` element and add it into an output array...

```
$out = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($data, $key ) use (&$out)    {
    if ( $key == "attr2" )  {
        $out[] = $data;
    }
});
```